# Postgresql serial or custom primary key

Tags: database, postgresql, pdo

I have a table like  :

```
customers:

id    name   amount   address   transaction_id   display   created_at and so on
```

id is serial and primary key.

I am sending id with other payment details to a payment gateway. Id is returned by payment gateway, which i use to update my record,such as transaction id, payment_status.

Is it ok to use serial as a primary key or should i create a custom one.

Comment: imho as long as your id is consistent, which means that you have control of it in a pk, it does not really matter whether you use a serial number or a custom id, both are fine.

Comment: Can you give more details? Does the gateway return a *new* id that will be used to insert into the `customers` table?

Comment: generating custom id's and inserting is a non go because off **race conditions** .. Why would to write client application code for something the database supports out off the box and impossible to break with **race conditions**..

Comment: .. If you want a more unpredicable id (for the outside users) you can use a (before insert) trigger and the pgcrypto module to auto generate some hash (md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384 or sha512) from the serial or use a view where you generate the hash on the fly when you select from the view... Time for PostgreSQL to support virtual columns or the so called generated columns like some other databases support.

Comment: if the id is not exposed to the outside, imho it is fine to use serial. But if your id is exposed to the outside, for obvious security reasons, you don't want to make it easy to find the next id stored in the db based on a given on. especially if your app is about payments.